# igraph Breadth-first search (bfs) callback function R

Tags: r, igraph, breadth-first-search

Is it possible to use the callback function to stop the search when the cumulative sum of assigned vertex weights achieved a threshold value?
Thanks,

Following the pseudo code:

```
graph1 <- make_ring(10) 
weights <- c(1:10)

func1 <- function(graph, data, extra = weights) {
      #stop bfs when the cumulative sum of vertices weights is >= 8
}

bfs <- bfs(graph1, root = 2, callback= func1, unreachable = FALSE)
```